# I need to make Dynamic Collapsible Panel in ASP.NET using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need To make Dynamic Collapsible Panel in ASP.NET using C#.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: as a side not to this question, i want to add something.
people seem to have forgoten that as lightweight the pages are,
they are more popular in search engines.
if the whole site is not using JQuery, a simple JS solution is prefered on adding a 65k file to the site/page.
The JS function will not take even 5kb, which is a BIG diffrence.

Comment: @Dementic I agree, but people tend to use "simple" solutions like AJAX Toolkit or other similar libraries that add far more overhead in terms of size of the generated page. I can say that I evolved in ASP.NET development by using less and less server side controls and solutions, relying more on html/javascript and using server side code merely as a Service layer. My websites are running now much smoother, are better indexed and I develop much faster.

Comment: i do understand what you are saying, but i cant stop myself from giving an example of one of the latest sites i did, which did use a lot of JS. but the total filesize of the JS was 23kb, so i still managed to save some overhead. even due JS libraries are a lot easier to work with, people tend to forget that they are "help" libraries for mass programming, and not for doing small things.
of example, i seen a website using JQuery, just to do an 1 ajax call. its just WRONG...

Answer (score 2):

My best bet would be using JQuery and in Javascript slideUp/slideDown the  containing the panel.

Something like this:

```
    <div id="pnlPanelHeader">
        Caption <a href="#" onclick="$('#pnlPanel').toggle();return false;">Toggle</a>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPanel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        Content to be collapsed
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [collapsible panel](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx) extender of the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/), or one of the jQuery plugins listed [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/collapsible).

You can also use jQuery UI's [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) widget for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik have a free (for non-commercial use) library of controls (both ASPX and Razor), which include what you're asking for:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/panelbar